# Solving a 7x7 maze puzzle

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i came across [this fun puzzle](http://www.logicmazes.com/n2mz.html) while being on vacation.

It was designed by Robert Abbott and painted into the grass of a Wisconsin farm. Robert succeeded into making it seem really easy to solve. Well, it is not. I spent hours with my friends wandering the puzzle and left frustrated.

I decided to solve it using computers. chose javascript because it made it easy to visualize the process and solution.

Initially i started with a brute force algorithm, which run for hours and got me nowhere. Than i shifted to this final one (below). I just kinda came up with this recursive solution that explores all paths, and terminates any path that comes across a previously visited node, so the one that makes it to the end should be the shortest one in (my) theory. I am wondering if this is a known algorithm (and how i botched it), and if there is a better way to achieve this. Also this algo appears to find the answer in 28 steps (including entry step).. A friend of mine solved this using an algo that works its way back from the end which supposedly solved it in 20 steps.

anyways, [the working solution can be seen here](http://pics.nicecomeback.com/puzzle.html).

here is the recursive function:

```
_delay = 50;
_successfulSteps = null; 
function findRecursive(params){
    var cell = params[0];
    var steps = params[1];
    var history = params[2];
    var x = getX(cell);
    var y = getY(cell);
    var steps = getCellSteps(cell);
    markCellActive(x,y);

    var h = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<history.length; i++) {
        h.push(history[i]);
    };
    h.push([getX(cell),getY(cell)]);

    if (steps == 0) {
        var sp = $('#solutionSpan')[0];
        sp.innerHTML = 'solved in ' + h.length + ' steps';
        return;
    }

    for (var i = history.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (x == history[i][0] && y == history[i][1]) {
            // this cell already processed
            console.log('terminating recursion for: ' + y + ':' + x);
            return;
        }
    };

    var rightCell = getRightCell(x,y, steps);
    var leftCell = getLeftCell(x,y, steps);
    var upCell = getUpCell(x,y, steps);
    var downCell = getDownCell(x,y, steps);

            // add delay to visualize the process 
    if (rightCell){
        setTimeout(findRecursive, _delay, [rightCell, steps, h]);
    }
    if (leftCell){
        setTimeout(findRecursive, _delay, [leftCell, steps, h]);
    }
    if (upCell){
        setTimeout(findRecursive, _delay, [upCell, steps, h]);
    }
    if (downCell){
        setTimeout(findRecursive, _delay, [downCell, steps, h]);
    }

}
```

(i should note that this is not the prettiest code and i'm not looking for a way to reduce # of lines or anything, just to find a better algorithm)

Comment: The [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) can be solved using [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Comment: since each node is forcing a # of subsequent steps, i believe it's not as simple as finding the least # of steps between 2 points. Those steps are already routed and the problem is finding that route. is that still the same as shortest path problem ?

Comment: @SonicSoul: Yes.  This puzzle can be represented as a directed graph.  Each node has a directed edge to each node that is N spaces away.

Comment: Thanks for the cool puzzle. I am learning Scala and just completed an exhaustive, breadth-first search algorithm. I'm pretty sure it's ten times as long as it needs to be. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're finding all solutions, but because the code overwrites the `<span>` for every solution found you only see the last one. Try this:

```
sp.innerHTML += 'solved in ' + h.length + ' steps<br/>';
```

You're performing a breadth-first search of all possible paths through the maze which is what I ended up going with. By scheduling timer events you're essentially queueing up cells. I did the same but with an actual queue of cells to visit.

This is the core of my Scala version.

```scala
// pathTo tracks the best path to each point
// moves(Point) returns the number in that cell

val queue = new Queue[Point]
queue enqueue new Point(0, 0)  // start from top-left
while (!queue.isEmpty) {
    val start = queue dequeue
    val path = pathTo(start)
    (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT) foreach { direction =>
        val end = start.move(direction, moves(start))
        if (end != None && !pathTo.contains(end)) {
            pathTo(end) = path + end
            queue enqueue end
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i don't stop after first solution. if any others were found, it should print it again.. although that has not happened, but technically the code is not stopping after first success

Comment: ok good point!.. heheh.. i do see it solved like 10 times now.. and the least steps was 19 :)

Comment: i kind of assumed i'd see the span rewrite, since i had that delay.. but the delay was not big enough to notice the rewrites.

Comment: If you're counting the starting square as the first step, I got the same answer as you.

Comment: well my question was more about figuring out if this is the best algorithm.. if if there is a better way to find the answer.. but i'll accept if there arent any other suggestions

Comment: very nice thanks! what platform do you use scala on? what do you find most useful about this language ?

Comment: I'm running it on a Windows 7 machine for now inside Eclipse since I'm learning the language at home. I just got started last week so haven't gotten beyond the small stuff. The syntax is quite expressive. :)